# Как сделать так чтоб скрипт запускался как утилита из командной строки, без указания пути до исполняемого файла?

Tags: linux, bash, консоль

Как сделать так чтоб скрипт запускался как утилита из командной строки, без указания пути до исполняемого файла?
к примеру есть баш скрипт `exemple.sh`, как сделать так чтоб он запускался из любого место по команде `exemple`

Comment: Утилиты командной строки следует запускать указывая путь до исполняемого файла.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

или

```
alias exemple=/home/me/scripts/exemple.sh
```

или

```
ln -s /home/me/scripts/exemple.sh /usr/local/bin/exemple
```